# Macro autofill loop very slow with large dataset

Tags: vba, performance, autofill

I'm trying to find real estate listings that match a certain criteria and output the desired listings that match those criteria. My code works start to finish but an intermediate step takes 20+ minutes if the listings are >3000 or more. My goal is to do it with 40,000 or more listings.

My bottleneck for speed is here:

```
Sub FillTable()

                With Application
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                    .ScreenUpdating = False
                    .DisplayStatusBar = False
                    .EnableEvents = False
                End With

                Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables(1).ManualUpdate = True

    Worksheets("Pivot").Select
    Dim lrowcount as integer
    Dim lcolcount as integer
    lrowcount = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Rows.Count
    lcolcount = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Columns.Count + 1
LLC = lcolcount - 3


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

Dim x as integer

For x = 8 to lrowcount step 8

    Range(Cells(x, 4), Cells (x, lcolcount)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(Pivot!R[3]C" & LLC & "=Pivot!R[2]C, Pivot!R[5]C" & LLC & ">Pivot!R[4]C-R1C6, Pivot!R[5]C" & LLC & "<Pivot!R[4]C+R1C6, Pivot!R[7]C" & LLC & ">Pivot!R[6]C+R2C6, LEFT(Pivot!R[1]C3,6)=LEFT(Pivot!R7C,6)), 1, 0)"

Next


End Sub
```

I've tried loops, autofill, with/endwith, range.formula placement and the speed seems to be about the same. I know that select and autofill can be slow and was able to eliminate them, but it's still slow. I also recognize that the nature of the formula requires a lot of work, just wondering if <10 minutes code run time is a reasonable expectation. This current code is the fastest I've been able to find but it still OFTEN just gets stuck in a 'not responding' cycle and tops 30 or more minutes to run. Any ideas on how to make this faster?

FULL EXPLANATION, IF NEEDED:
So how I've set it up, there are 2 large sets of listings, old listings and new listings on Sheet 1 and 2 respectively. These are then formatted into a pivot table on sheet 3. My issues starts in sheet 4. I've created a table with a complex formula pulling 8 different cells from data on sheet 3 and 4.

I want this code to place the formula in cell D8 and across horizontally to the end of the table, so there would be one line of data across most of the row (D8: D'lcolcount'). I then want it to skip 7 rows and place again across a row at D16:D'lcolcount' and so on until lrowcount (ideally thousands of rows below). If I run the code below about 100 times by hand it still takes a full 60 seconds. If i run the entire code, it often stops working.

I'd prefer not to include the entire sheet but can if needed.

Comment: What is LLC here?

Comment: Whoops, LLC = lcolcount - 3    ....I must've deleted it forgetting that it fit my needs better and clearly forgot it was in the formula

Comment: Have you tried assigning the formula to the block in one shot `Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells (lrowcount, lcolcount)).FormulaR1C1 = ...` ?

Comment: Yes I believe so, as in not using With or loops or anything right? If so, it's the same result. It seems to just get overwhelmed. With the above formula I timed it as follows: 500 listings takes roughly 10 s. 1000 takes 40, 2000 takes 180...it seems that if I double the listings, I quadruple the processing time.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `step 8` in your loop counter, so my suggestion makes no sense...

Comment: No worries, I did try that just to see, but it took a long time. Though if there is a faster shortcut for that method, I don't necessarily mind if all of the rows in between are full of formulas...just figured it'd take longer

Comment: Don't you have Calculation set to manual though?  Are these formulas calculating as you add them?

Comment: Let me try that again today when I get home from work. But if I remember right, it still takes a very long time just to place each formula even if not calculating. I'll get back to you tonight.

Comment: So if anything, it's about 10% faster to assign the formula to the block in one shot as mentioned, rather than looping. It does not calculate until after the formulas have been placed. Is there a way to assign the formula to the array in one shot, while still skipping the 7 rows each time...without using a loop? Or rather than skipping 7 rows, is there a way for my formula to 'autofill' but skip 7 cells with the reference value (so if the reference value goes from D8 to D15, can I have it jump like that even if the 'autofill' is only offsetting down a single row)

Comment: I can send the spreadsheet if it'd help a lot